# Web API custom validation to check string against list of approved values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to validate an input on a Web API REST command. I'd like it to work something like `State` below being decorated with an attribute that limits the valid values for the parameter.

```
public class Item {
    ...

    // I want State to only be one of "New", "Used", or "Unknown"
    [Required]
    [ValidValues({"New", "Used", "Unknown"})]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this without going against the grain of Web API. Ideally the approach would be similar to Ruby on Rails' [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create a custom validation attribute derived from `ValidationAttribute` and override the `IsValid` member function.

```
public class ValidValuesAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
  string[] _args;

  public ValidValuesAttribute(params string[] args)
  {
    _args = args;
  }

  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
    if (_args.Contains((string)value))
      return ValidationResult.Success;
    return new ValidationResult("Invalid value.");
  }
}
```

Then you can do

```
[ValidValues("New", "Used", "Unknown")]
```

*The above code has not been compiled or tested.*

Comment: Pretty good for not having compiled or testing. This worked with minimal tweaking: The constructor didn't like the `params` before the `args` parameter. Also, the attribute looks like this `[ValidValues(new[] {"New", "Used", "Unknown"})]`

Comment: I compiled the code above.  I had to make the constructor public. Aside from that, it worked as expected.  For me, the `params` worked.

Comment: What if I don't want to pass it a hardcoded list? For example, a reference to an existing list. Any ideas for that which still use dependency injection versus something like a Singleton or ServiceLocator? I suppose that isn't possible because Attributes can impact compile time.

Comment: Is this approach reflected in the Swagger documentation? - in a similar way that an enum would be?  (here's your available options)

Comment: @RobMcCabe I don't know the answer to that, but if I was to guess, I'd say no, not without more work to make it so.

Answer (score 1):

How is the value passed to the API? Is it a query param or is it in the body? I'd generally just do a check at the request handler level. If you put accepted values in a List or array you can just used the `Contains` extension method.

```
  if (validStates.Contains(input))
  {
     return MethodThatProcessesRequest(requiredData);
  }
  else
  {
     return ErrorHandlingMethod(requiredData);
  }
```

This type of validation should be done servers side. Feel free to restrict the input on the UI but if you're making a REST API it should validate all input regardless of what *your* client is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Implement IValidatableObject for the Item which would require you to implement Validate method, then in the Validate write your condition to check whether it is valid, something like:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext context) {
    if (!States.contains(this.State)){
        yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid state.", new[] { "State" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this using a regular expression as below:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("New|Used|Unknown", ErrorMessage = "Invalid State")]
 public string State{ get; set; }
```

More details can by found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions)